# Passing a parameter into constructor generates an ng2003 error using Angular 9

Tags: angular, constructor, angular9

New to Angular and to programming in general. I'd like to know why this simple code wouldn't work in Angular 9.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-record-list',
  templateUrl: './record-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./record-list.component.css'],
})
export class RecordListComponent implements OnInit {
  records;
  recordsFiltered;
  searchTerm: string;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('OnInit records: ', this.records);
  }

  constructor(title) {
    this.records = title;
  }
}

let model1 = new RecordListComponent('Idea 1 title');
```

Instead, I receive this error in the terminal:

ERROR in src/app/record-list/record-list.component.ts:37:15 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'title' of class 'RecordListComponent'.
    no type or decorator

Comment: The framework takes care of creating component classes for you. You can’t really do this (and why would you want to?)

Comment: Angular classes decorated with `@Component` decorator aren't typical Typescript classes. Arguments to component constructors are usually dependency injections. If you're new to Angular please see here: https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces some basics of Angular. If you're new to programming in general, I'd recommend you to first go through an introduction on Typescript. Jumping directly to Angular might lead to difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both comments are correct. So the best way is to set the data (title) via @Input decorator:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-record-list',
    templateUrl: './record-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./record-list.component.css'],
})
export class RecordListComponent {

    records;
    recordsFiltered;
    searchTerm: string;
    @Input() title: string;

}
```

In the template of the parent component:

```
<app-record-list [title]="'your title'"></app-record-list>
```

See [angular doc: input decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)